# Discord.py information storage

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I have made kick and ban commands and now I am working on the mute command. I haven't got any issues however I would like to store information in a json file. For example when I mute someone, his name will be stored in the json file so the script can read this name to activate the mute command only for him... Please help me with this issue...

Also this is my code

```py
@client.command(name="kick")
async def kickcommand(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    guild = ctx.guild
    
    mbed = discord.Embed(
        title = f"Kicked {member}",
        description = f"{member} has been kicked from the server because {reason} ... Bye Bye :)"
    )
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.ban_members:
        await ctx.send(embed=mbed)
        await guild.kick(member)
```

Comment: This shouldn't be too difficult. First of all make a simple data class where the properties are all the stuff you want to store (like name, time, action, etc..) [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp) is how you can convert a class object into a JSON string and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_handling.asp) how to handle files.So if you want to store something, simply instantiate a new object from your class, fill in the data, convert it to a json string and save it to file :)

Comment: Hello there, thank you for your response... Can you provide an example more relevant to my case?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
import json

class myJsonDataClass:
  def __init__(self, name, time, action):
    self.Name = name
    self.Time = time
    self.Action = action



banData = myJsonDataClass("John", "Monday", "kicked")

myJsonString = json.dumps(banData.__dict__)

print(myJsonString)
```

This prints `{"Name": "John", "Time": "Monday", "Action": "kicked"}` for example, which you can save to a json file.

Comment: Hello there, thank you for your response... After reading your answers I understood how json works with python... However how can I replace these banData with the actual bans? Can I do it with the member variable?

Comment: I have not used python for discord servers, however `banData.__dict__` simply makes a dictionary from the object, which you can serialize. You can try to do this with the actual ban object. If not, what says you shouldn't create your own data class and set your actual ban according to the information you saved?

Comment: I will try to use the actual ban target object and I will see how it goes...

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, and then building from Rolands answer, you could do something like this:

```py
import json

with open("userData.json","r") as input:
    existingData = json.load(input)

if existingData == None:
    existingData = {}

existingData.update(banData.__dict__)

with open("userData.json","w") as output:
    json.dump(existingData,output)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response... I fully understood this part of the code. If I need any help with it I will ask for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So if I get it right... This is what I have to do?:

```py
@client.command(name="kick")
async def kickcommand(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    guild = ctx.guild
    
    mbed = discord.Embed(
        title = f"Kicked {member}",
        description = f"{member} has been kicked from the server because {reason} ... Bye Bye :)"
    )
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.ban_members:
        await ctx.send(embed=mbed)
        await guild.kick(member)


        class myJsonDataClass:
            def __init__(name, time, action):
                self.Name = name
                self.Time = time
                self.Action = action
        banData = myJsonDataClass(str(member), "Monday", "kicked")

        myJsonString = json.dumps(banData.__dict__)

        print(myJsonString)


        with open("userData.json","r") as input:
            existingData = json.load(input)

        if existingData == None:
            existingData = {}

        existingData.update(banData.__dict__)

        with open("userData.json","w") as output:
            json.dump(existingData,output)
```

Comment: I mean, define the class in the main scope, just a habit of mine to define classes at the top. Other than that, yea